# Spring JDBC tomcat resources locked - 100% CPU

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc

I have an issue happening once in a while, with a tomcat server run a Spring JDBC application.

When this happens we can see that the tomcat server is running 100% of the CPU of the machine, and just doesn't respond.

The only information I have in the tomcat traces are related to:

- JDBC connection failures
- Database deadlocks

The JDBC issues are like:

```
        2020-10-31 00:03:09,804 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01>
2020-10-31 00:03:09,804 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <Read timed out ClientConnectionId:138ee420-6f86-40b7-8b56-201bc3809d4a>
2020-10-31 00:03:09,804 ERROR [org.springframework.aop.interceptor.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler] - <Unexpected error occurred invoking async method 'public void service.impl.AnalyticServiceImpl.recordRequest(analytics.Request)'.>
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:439)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.addRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.anonym.cdr.service.impl.AnalyticServiceImpl.recordRequest(AnalyticServiceImpl.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1700)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:48)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:159)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1512)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:45)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Read timed out ClientConnectionId:138ee420-6f86-40b7-8b56-201bc3809d4a
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1654)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1789)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:4838)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:6154)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:6106)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2907)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1185)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
    ... 26 more
2020-10-31 00:03:09,804 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null>
2020-10-31 00:03:09,804 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <Already closed.>
2020-10-31 00:03:10,007 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01>
2020-10-31 00:03:10,007 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <Read timed out ClientConnectionId:d2b4e443-348a-4f77-9d85-e81de9a674ae>
```

and then I also have deadlocks messages like:

```
2020-10-31 00:12:56,434 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001>
2020-10-31 00:12:56,434 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <Transaction (Process ID 101) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.>
2020-10-31 00:12:56,450 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001>
2020-10-31 00:12:56,450 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <Transaction (Process ID 99) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.>
2020-10-31 00:13:01,036 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001>
2020-10-31 00:13:01,036 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <Transaction (Process ID 54) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.>
2020-10-31 00:13:01,130 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001>
2020-10-31 00:13:01,130 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <Transaction (Process ID 122) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.>
2020-10-31 00:13:01,161 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001>
2020-10-31 00:13:01,161 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <Transaction (Process ID 110) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.>
2020-10-31 00:13:01,177 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001>
2020-10-31 00:13:01,177 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <Transaction (Process ID 114) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.>
```

This is an MS SQL Server database behind.
This happens every night at the same time. So I am thinking about a batch or maintenance process running on the SQL server database generating these errors.

But what I would like to understand is why the tomcat process is using 100% of the CPU and is not responding.

The only explanation I have so far, because the only error I have in the tomcat traces are related to these JDBC exceptions, is that when the JDBC pool resources I locked like this, they are never released, and after a while I have all the pool resources locked and waiting.
But if I get these exception errors to me it means that the transactions was released by the exception. So I am not sure.

In tomcat, context.xml file I have defined:

```
<!-- JNDI JDBC connection -->
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/DB"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="30"
        maxWait="10000"
        username="adm"
        password="pwd"
        driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://SSQL16\mydb;databaseName=dbname;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;sendUnicode=false;"
        validationQuery="select 1 from myClass"
        testOnBorrow="true"
    />
```

The Spring configuration for the JDBC accesses is:

```
    <!-- JNDI Data source configuration -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="DataSourceJNDI" jndi-name="jdbc/DB" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

and

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSourceJNDI" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PU" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Do you think that my assumption that the pool connections are locked and never released is correct?
If yes how can I solve this?

Thanks and regards

Gilles

Comment: Your assumption seems quite oversimplified. I'd suggest you do less assuming and more investigating. For example the deadlocks in the database are things you generally should be interested about. You don't want those in your normal day-to-day operations.

Comment: Yes I agree. Especially because we have two servers calling this DB, and the second one doesn't have this issue at all, which is strange. In the meantime I'd like to know if it is plausible that the connections are not being released or not. Because in any case it must be fixed

Comment: You mean a simple connection leak? No I don't see any evidence towards that. The read timeout and deadlocks suggest action on the DB side.

Comment: thank you I am going to investigate in this way. I am worried by the fact that the tomcat process is using 100% CPU of the virtual machines. From the logs the only thing I can imagine is the connection being locked and the pool being full. But I have never seen this before. I am wondering if it is possible that the DB never returns an answer and that the connection remains opened and waiting

Comment: Obviously if the DB is busy with something, transactions take longer times and less connections are available, and you may even run out. Ask your DBA or the person with the most DBA experience to investigate what's going on. If you don't have that kind of person, head on to https://dba.stackexchange.com and start reading. These aren't the kinds of problems you solve with lucky guesses. Software development isn't that easy. Databases aren't that easy.

Comment: You need to observe what's happening at the database level when you get those problems. So database logs, not application logs. Go to the root of the problem and work your way backwards from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help that was really the cause. I was focusing too much on java side. The deadlocks happen because of database backup. At this time, because the server is open 24/24 there are connections happening at this time and they are locked.  It seems that all the connections are not released properly because I have error message telling me that the pool is full and that there is no idle connection.